# certain utf characters do not show up on browsers and fails python script

Tags: c#, python, windows-7, utf-8, character-encoding

I generated a SQL script from a C# application on Windows 7. The name entries have utf8 characters. It works find on Windows machine where I use a python script to populate the db. Now the same script fails on Linux platform complaining about those special characters.

Similar things happened when I generated XML file containing utf chars on Windows 7 but fails to show up on browsers (IE, Firefox.).

I used to generate such scripts on Windows XP and it worked perfect everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give a small example of a script with "utf8 characters" in the "name entries". Are you sure that they are `utf8` and not some windows encoding like `cp1252'? What makes you sure? Try this in Python at the command prompt:

```
... python -c "print repr(open('small_script.sql', 'rb').read())"
```

The interesting parts of the output are where it uses `\xhh` (where h is any hex digit) to represent non-ASCII characters e.g. `\xc3\xa2` is the UTF-8 encoding of the small a with circumflex accent. Show us a representative sample of such output. Also tell us the exact error message(s) that you get from that sample script.

**Update:** It appears that you have data encoded in `cp1252` or similar (`Latin1` aka `ISO-8859-1` is as rare as hen's teeth on Windows). To get that into `UTF-8` using Python, you'd do `fixed_data = data.decode('cp1252').encode('utf8')`; I can't help you with C# -- you may like to ask a separate question about that.

Comment: Here is the output produced from the command above
INSERT INTO customer (id, name)VALUES (2,'Mic M\xfcnchen');\r\n 
.The actual name is "Mic München"

Thank you.

Comment: That means it's not UTF-8. In UTF-8, `ü` would be `\xc3\xbc`. `\xfc` means it's in latin-1 or cp1252 or some other encoding (quite a few single-byte encodings use `\xfc` for that character.

Comment: Exactly, I found it. The file seems to be in cp1252. Now how do I force the C# application to save the names in UTF-8 format? OR how do I change the Windows 7 encoding from cp1252 to utf-8?

Comment: I found the way to force file created in C# apps to be in utf-8. We need to set the encoding param to Encoding.UTF8 while doing new StreamWriter

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using python, make sure you are using [Unicode strings](http://evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html).

For example:

```
s = "Hello world"          # Regular String
u = u"Hello Unicode world" # Unicdoe String
```

Edit:
Here's an example of reading from a UTF-8 file from the linked site:

```
import codecs
fileObj = codecs.open( "someFile", "r", "utf-8" )
u = fileObj.read() # Returns a Unicode string from the UTF-8 bytes in the file
```